# Move Last element to first with Node class

Tags: java, move

I made linkedlist with queue, but I need help for one method

```
public class QueueLinkedList{
private Node first;
private Node last;
public QueueLinkedList(){
   first = null;
   last = null;
}

class Node{
   public Object data;
   public Node next;
}
    ...
public void lastToFirst(){
   Node newNode = new Node();
   newNode.data = last.data;
   newNode.next = first;
   first = newNode;
}
```

and when I run my demo class with

```
q.add("1");
q.add("2");
q.add("3");
q.add("4");
q.lastToFirst();
while(!q.isEmpty()){
   System.out.print(q.remove());
}
```

my expected value was 4123

but It gave me 41234.

How could I remove the last value 4?

Comment: all u need to do is `last.next = first`;

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're not updating your reference to last.